# C++ - How to declare a function template friend for a class template

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, ostream

I have a class template that will output a list of objects stored in the array. I am getting the following error and I am confused where the error is caused since the error is in the .obj and .exe file.

> 1 unresolved externals (proj08.exe line 1)
>   
> unresolved external symbol "class std::basic_ostream > & __cdecl operator<<(class std::basic_ostream > &,class MyVector)" (??6@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@AAV01@V?$MyVector@N@@@Z) referenced in function _main   (porj08.obj line 1)

**proj08.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include "MyVector.h"

const double FRACTION = 0.5; 

int main()
{
    cout << "\nCreating a vector of doubles named Sam\n";
    MyVector<double> sam;

    cout << "\nPush 12 values into the vector.";
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
        sam.push_back(i + FRACTION);

    cout << "\nHere is sam: ";
    cout << sam;
    cout << "\n---------------\n";

    cout << "\nCreating an empty vector named joe";
    MyVector<double> joe;

    // test assignment
    joe = sam;

    cout << "\nHere is joe after doing an assignment:\n ";
    cout << joe;
    cout << "\n---------------\n";

    // test the copy constructor
    MyVector<double> bill = sam;

    cout << "\nHere is bill after creating it using the copy constructor:\n ";
    cout << bill;
    cout << "\n---------------\n";

    cout << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

**MyVector.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class MyVector
{

private:
    int vectorSize;
    int vectorCapacity;
    T *vectorArray;

public:
    MyVector() {
        vectorArray = new T[10];
    }
    T size();
    T capacity();
    void clear();
    void push_back(T n);
    T at(int n);

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, MyVector<T> vt);

    MyVector<T> operator=(MyVector<T>&);
};

/*
 * TEMPLATE FUNCTIONS
 */

//Return array size
template<class T>
T MyVector<T>::size()
{
    return vectorSize;
}

// Return array capacity
template<class T>
T MyVector<T>::capacity()
{
    return vectorCapacity;
}

// clear array values
template<class T>
void MyVector<T>::clear()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < vectorSize; i++)
    {
        vectorArray[i] = '\0';
    }

    vectorSize = 0;
    vectorCapacity = 2;
}


// Add number to array and double array size if needed
template<class T>
void MyVector<T>::push_back(T n)
{
    int test = 100;
    if (vectorCapacity > vectorSize)
    {
        vectorArray[vectorSize] = n;
        vectorSize++;

    }
    else {

        if (vectorCapacity == 0) {
            vectorArray = new T[4];
            vectorArray[0] = n;
            vectorCapacity = 4;
            vectorSize++;
        }
        else {

            int newCapacity = vectorCapacity * 2;

            // Dynamically allocate a new array of integers what is somewhat larger than the existing array.An algorithm that is often used is to double the size of the array.

            int *tempArray = new int[newCapacity];

            // Change capacity to be the capacity of the new array.

            vectorCapacity = newCapacity;

            // Copy all of the numbers from the first array into the second, in sequence.

            for (int i = 0; i < MyVector::size(); i++)
            {
                tempArray[i] = vectorArray[i];
            }

            delete[] vectorArray;
            vectorArray = new T[newCapacity];

            for (int i = 0; i < MyVector::size(); i++)
            {
                vectorArray[i] = tempArray[i];
            }

            delete[] tempArray;

            // Add the new element at the next open slot in the new array.

            vectorArray[vectorSize] = n;

            // Increment the size;

            vectorSize++;

        }
    }
}

// Return Value and given point in array
template<class T>
T MyVector<T>::at(int n)
{
    return vectorArray[n];
}

// Set one vector to equil another
template<class T>
MyVector<T> MyVector<T>::operator=(MyVector<T>& right) {

    if (vectorCapacity < right.vectorCapacity) {
        if (vectorCapacity != 0)
            delete[] vectorArray;
        vectorArray = new T[right.vectorCapacity];
        vectorCapacity = right.vectorCapacity;
    }
    vectorSize = right.size();

    // Assign values from left to right
    for (int i = 0; i < vectorSize; i++)
    {
        vectorArray[i] = right.at(i);
    }

    return *this;
}

// Cout Vector
template<class T>
ostream& operator << (ostream& os, MyVector<T> vt)
{
    T size = vt.size();

    for (T i = 0; i < size; i++) {

        os << "index " << i << " is " << vt.at(i) << endl;

    }

    return os;
}
```

Comment: As a side comment, consider passing `MyVector<T> vt` by `const` reference, `friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const MyVector<T>& vt)`, so you don't make an additional gratuitous copy.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have to declare `friend` as a function template if you want to match the one you defined:

```
template <typename U> // use U, so it doesn't clash with T
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, MyVector<U> vt);
```

**If a `friend` function is declared for a class template, that does not make it a function template.**

Comment: An alternative is to define it inline inside the class. In that case, the function is found via ADL (the definition is visible in the outside scope *only* via ADL).

Comment: Another alternative is to not use the `friend` declaration at all, since the implementation only uses public members

Comment: Well, there's that :D

Comment: The only issue here is that the function in MyVector<int> class is also friends with MyVector<double>, MyVector<char> and so on with other instances of the templated class. See https://web.mst.edu/~nmjxv3/articles/templates.html

Answer (score 7):

[@LogicStuff's answer is perfectly valid.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33861178/3093378) I'd like to clarify what exactly happens in your code and how you may avoid it using an alternative, as I believe most C++ programmers bumped at least once into this issue. Basically, when the template is instantiated, say

```
MyVector<int> something;
```

then automatically the `friend` declaration is bounded to the template type, in this case `int`, so the compiler generates

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, MyVector<int> vt);
```

However, this is just a declaration. Your latter definition

```
template<class T>
ostream& operator << (ostream& os, MyVector<T> vt)
```

has no relation whatsoever with the one for `int`, and because the former is a better match, whenever you attempt

```
cout << something;
```

the compiler tries to invoke the `int` version (which has no definition). So you get a linker error.

An alternative widely used is to **define** your operator inline in class, like

```
friend ostream& operator << (ostream& os, MyVector<T> vt)
{
    T size = vt.size();

    for (T i = 0; i < size; i++) {

        os << "index " << i << " is " << vt.at(i) << endl;

    }

    return os;
}
```

Now, each instantiation of your `MyVect` produces a valid definition of `operator<<` bounded to the corresponding template type. Note that the operator itself **is not a member function**, and it is visible in the global namespace only via [Argument Dependent Lookup (ADL)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl). This trick is called *friend name injection*, used widely in [*the Barton–Nackman trick*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barton%E2%80%93Nackman_trick), and you are able to successfully use it because in a call like

```
cout << something;
```

the call is translated to

```
operator<< (std::cout, something)
```

and becuase `something` is of type `MyVector<int>`, the definition of `operator<<` is found via ADL. If your `operator<<` takes e.g. an `int` as a second parameter, it won't be found via ADL, since fundamental types do not have an associated namespace.

Comment: So it's rather a fault of definition that it doesn't match the declaration. If `operator<<` (friend) was directly defined at that place, the could would be valid.