# c++ implicit conversion on user-defined operator for template classes

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, c++14, friend-function

I have a struct template `A<x>` and a `+` operator with `int`.

```
#include <iostream>
template<int x>
struct A{
    int a;  
};
template<int x>
int operator+(A<x> a, int b){
    return a.a+b;
}
```

I created a struct template `B<x>`, which is convertible to `A<x>`.

```
template<int x>
struct B{
    int b=3;
    operator A<x>(){
        return {b+10};
    }
};
```

Now I want `B<x>` to be converted to `A<x>` when calling `B<x> + int`.

```
int main(){
    std::cout<<(A<12>{9}+10)<<std::endl;//OK
    std::cout<<(B<12>{9}+10)<<std::endl;//Error
    return 0;
}
```

I read [Implicit conversion when overloading operators for template classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8890051/implicit-conversion-when-overloading-operators-for-template-classes) and wrote

```
template<int x>
struct B{
    int b=3;
    operator A<x>(){
        return {b+10};
    }
    friend int operator+(A<x> a, int b);
};
```

, but it didn't work because the declared `friend int operator+(A<x> a, int b)` does not match `template<int x> int operator+(A<x> a, int b)`.

I read [C++ - How to declare a function template friend for a class template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33861151/c-how-to-declare-a-function-template-friend-for-a-class-template) and made friend declaration template, but it didn't work because the template parameter couldn't be deduced.

Of course I could write operator+ for both A and B, but I have dozens of operators and I don't want to do it.

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: I think, you can't use same operator that, either you declare template friend operator inside B, or unless  if B would be derived from A

Comment: can't you make `operator+` template?

Comment: @W.F. Right, it  isn't declared as template for in provided code,  its template should be defined in class to exist at same time as class template instance. if B is derived from it would be able to use  operator that is defined for A.

Comment: Can you touch `A`?

Comment: @T.C. yes, I can change A too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to edit Barrys answer with the following (runnable) code, that produces the correct output, but it was rejected there.

I'll add it here in case anyone else is curious.

```
#include <iostream>

template <int x>
struct A {
    int a;
    friend int operator+(A a, int b) { return a.a + b; }
};

template <int x>
struct B {
    int b;
    operator A<x>() { return {b+10}; }
    friend int operator+(A<x>, int );
};

int main() {
    std::cout << (A<12>{9} + 10) << std::endl;
    std::cout << (B<12>{9} + 10) << std::endl;
}
```

Which prints

```
19
29
```

Comment: Why is there an error, when I change friend int operator+(A<x>, int ); in struct B to something like friend int operator+(A<12>, int );? Shouldn't it lead to the same result?

Answer (score 5):

Looking at the two ways to make a non-member `operator+` for `A`, we can either make it a function template:

```
template <int x>
int operator+(A<x>, int);
```

which won't match `B<x>` because we're just doing template deduction, which doesn't allow for conversions.

Or, we can make it a friend non-template:

```
template <int x>
struct A {
    friend int operator+(A a, int );
};
```

which also won't match `B<x>` because name lookup won't consider that function. Unless, that is, we tell it to:

```
template <int x>
struct B {
    friend int operator+(A<x>, int ); // NB: not a template
};
```

*Now*, our original non-template `operator+` will be considered, the conversion will be performed as desired, and your code prints 29.

Comment: But then I would not be able to add an A<x> and an int.

Comment: @eivour Don't understand. Why do you think not?

Comment: @Barry I think he means that the binary `operator+(...)` previously defined outside both classes is no longer seen by `A`. Thus, you are correct that the code prints `29`, however the first line that prints `19` throws an error. From your answer this is not clear.

Comment: @pingul Huh? No, both work if you defined the `A` operator within the class.

Comment: @Barry you mean I should define(not declare) operator+ in both B<x> and A<x>?

Comment: @Barry Maybe you could provide a runnable example? I've tried to interpret   your answer, but I can't reproduce the result.

Comment: @Barry Oh I see; I had misinterpreted what you meant with making the function a _"friend non-template"_. I added a fully working example to your answer. Feel free to not accept it in case you don't like it, but it was necessary for me to understand your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You maybe have seen this already, but at least it is still possible to do an explicit cast, and it might be useful:

```
int main(){
    std::cout<<(A<12>{9}+10)<<std::endl;                     // prints 19
    std::cout<<(static_cast<A<12>>(B<12>{9})+10)<<std::endl; // prints 29
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope it may help you.

I have templated friend `operator+`

Derived from `A<x>` and it compiled, but after calling `friend operator+` variable `a` was uninit so i got immediate values. You have to set `a` somehow and this seems to work.

```
#include <iostream>

template<int x>
struct A
{
    int a{x};
};

template<int x>
int operator+(A<x> a, int b)
{
    return a.a+b;
}

template<int x>
struct B : A<x>
{
    int b;

template<int U>
    friend int operator+(A<U> a, int b);
};

int main(void)
{
    std::cout<< (A<20>{}+10)<<std::endl; // prints 30
    std::cout<< (B<10>{}+10)<<std::endl; // prints 20
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It compiles, but it changes the result. I want to add 10 automatically when converting from B to A. I also don't want users to change the value of a when using as B.

Comment: @eivour It doesnt change any instance of `A`. Ill take a look how could we add `10` when converting.