# How to use implicit conversion in template operator overloads?

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, implicit-conversion

I read [c++ implicit conversion on user-defined operator for template classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45726563/c-implicit-conversion-on-user-defined-operator-for-template-classes) and [Implicit conversion when overloading operators for template classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8890051/implicit-conversion-when-overloading-operators-for-template-classes).

I want to implement adjoint and dual numbers. Both numbers implement the same operators differently, but computation of `c = a(operator)b` takes the same information from the operator (namely the function of value, function of jacobi, and function of hessian, and so on). So it is natural to implement all operators with a template to be used for both types, and pass the operator information on to a `ResultWriter` that constructs `c`.

This is done below and it breaks because an implicit conversion would be necessary before a template deduction. In particular:

- operator plus fails when b is double
- whereas operator minus works with implicit conversion from double to NumberA since no template deduction is needed priorly.

### Question:

Is there a design pattern that will allow me to not have to write each operator redundantly for each of NumberA and NumberB?

```cpp
struct NumberBase{
    virtual double get()const=0;
};

struct NumberA: NumberBase{
    template<typename T> friend T operator+(T const&, T const&);
    double d;
    double get()const{ return d; }
    //
    NumberA(double const& d):d(d){}
    void operator=(NumberA const& rhs){ d = rhs.d; }
};

struct NumberB: NumberBase{
    double d;
    double get()const{ return d; }
    //
    NumberB(double const& d):d(d){}
    void operator=(NumberB const& rhs){ d = rhs.d; }
};

struct ResultWriter{
    double i;
    NumberA make_result(NumberA const& x, NumberA const& y){ NumberA z(x); z.d=i; return x; }
    NumberB make_result(NumberB const& x, NumberB const& y){ NumberB z(x); z.d=i; return x; }
};

// here go operators. I only want to write code for them once.
template<typename Tnumber>
Tnumber operator+(Tnumber const& a, Tnumber const& b){
    ResultWriter w; w.i=a.get()+b.get();
    return w.make_result(a,b);
}

NumberA operator-(NumberA const& a, NumberA const& b){
    ResultWriter w; w.i=42;
    return w.make_result(a,b);
}

NumberB operator-(NumberB const& a, NumberB const& b){
    ResultWriter w; w.i=42;
    return w.make_result(a,b);
}

int main(){
    double d = 3;
    NumberA f = 4;
    NumberA g = 5;
    //
    NumberA s1 = f - 2.0;
    NumberA t1 = f - g;
    //
    NumberA s2 = f + 2.0;
    NumberA t2 = f + g;
}
```

## What I tried

I tried several befriendings of operators in the Numbers. Admittedly however in practice, this would be as much boilerplate as redundant implementation because presumably both classes would have to befriend all operators (but I even haven't found yet a way how it would compile successfully).

I tried requirements in an attempt to force the compiler at trying the hinted types by the requirements, but all this seems of no use at all because still there is no implicit conversion attempt before template deduction.

I then tried overloading the operators with three templates and forcing by requirement that the return value type template equals one of the input templates, as otherwise the return type is indeterminate. But then the compiler is unable to deduce the templates altogether (and of course expecting a consumer to write the intended template types behind each operator is pointless).

So then lastly I tried inheritance in conjunction with only one template number type for the return value c. But then I cannot see a way how to decide in the operator the type of the return value.

### Towards a solution:

The following actually works in that for arbitrary many user-defined numbers NumberA,...,NumberD one will only have to write one redundant definitions of each operator. The trick goes by defining many requirements, but since doing this only once (i.e. O(1) ) for O(n) user-defined number-types and O(m) functions, it is actually helpful. But isn't there anything less ugly?

```cpp
#include<iostream>


struct NumberA{
    double d;
    //
    NumberA(double const& d):d(d){}
    void operator=(NumberA const& rhs){ d = rhs.d; }
};


// the requirements make it so that any feasible template candidate is always unique; i.e. there is never ambiguity.
template<typename Ta, typename Tb, typename Tc> concept is_Ta_and_Tc_NumberA = std::is_same_v<Ta,NumberA> and std::is_same_v<Tc,NumberA>;
template<typename Ta, typename Tb, typename Tc> concept is_Tb_and_Tc_NumberA = std::is_same_v<Tb,NumberA> and std::is_same_v<Tc,NumberA>;
template<typename Ta, typename Tb, typename Tc> concept is_Ta_and_Tb_and_Tc_NumberA = std::is_same_v<Ta,NumberA> and std::is_same_v<Tb,NumberA> and std::is_same_v<Tc,NumberA>;
template<typename Ta, typename Tb, typename Tc> concept is_typeconsistent_for_NumberA = is_Ta_and_Tc_NumberA<Ta,Tb,Tc> or is_Tb_and_Tc_NumberA<Ta,Tb,Tc> or is_Ta_and_Tb_and_Tc_NumberA<Ta,Tb,Tc>;



template<typename Ta, typename Tb, typename Tc>
struct ResultWriterSubroutine{
    static Tc make_result(){ static_assert(false); }
};


struct ResultWriter{
    //
    double i;
    //
    template<typename Ta, typename Tb, typename Tc> Tc make_result(Ta const& a, Tb const& b){
        return ResultWriterSubroutine<Ta,Tb,Tc>::make_result(a,b);
    }
    //
};


template<typename Ta>
    requires (!std::is_same_v<Ta,NumberA>)
struct ResultWriterSubroutine<Ta,NumberA,NumberA>{
    static NumberA make_result(Ta const& a, NumberA const& b){ return b; }
};
template<typename Tb>
    requires (!std::is_same_v<Tb,NumberA>)
struct ResultWriterSubroutine<NumberA,Tb,NumberA>{
    static NumberA make_result(NumberA const& a, Tb const& b){ return a; }
};
template<>
struct ResultWriterSubroutine<NumberA,NumberA,NumberA>{
    static NumberA make_result(NumberA const& a, NumberA const& b){ return a; }
};


// here go operators. I only want to write code for them once.
template<typename Ta, typename Tb=Ta>
    requires is_typeconsistent_for_NumberA<Ta,Tb,Ta> // or is_typeconsistent_for_NumberB; this is extendable
         and (!std::is_same_v<Ta,Tb>)
Ta operator+(Ta const& a, Tb const& b){
    ResultWriter w; w.i=42;
    return w.template make_result<Ta,Tb,Ta>(a,b);
}

template<typename Ta, typename Tb=Ta>
    requires is_typeconsistent_for_NumberA<Ta,Tb,Tb> // or is_typeconsistent_for_NumberB; this is extendable
Tb operator+(Ta const& a, Tb const& b){
    ResultWriter w; w.i=42;
    return w.template make_result<Ta,Tb,Tb>(a,b);
}

int main(){
    NumberA f(4);
    NumberA g(5);
    //
    NumberA s2 = f + 2.0;
    NumberA t2 = f + g;
    NumberA u2 = 2.0 + g;
}
```